# MySQL: Any performance impact on Select * vs select separately in subquery?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following `person` table, which has 1 million records:

#### person

```
#id, name,  ......50 more omitted fields
1,   Peter, ......
2,   Mary,  ......
```

---

Suppose that I would like to use the `id` to do further processing. And `person` table needs to be in a **subquery**

Would there be any performance benefit for me using (example is simplified)

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM person) p
```

Over

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM person) p
```

In other word, **if I `select` lots of fields in a subquery and didn't show, will it affect performance?**

---

I have been testing this with my result set and I see no performance difference, but maybe I am not using a large enough result sets.

But the `person` table will be growing from time to time, don't know how large will it get. So it will be nice to know this about this fact.

Comment: If you only use the **id** column, then use **select id** form

Comment: Yes I am using the `id` column. However perhaps I should be more specific about my question. I know already that `select id` will be the answer if were given the question in an exam. I am most curious as to how will the performance differs between the two.